# How to scroll map based on Google maps APIs

Tags: google-maps, blackberry, java-me

I want to make Custom Map based on Google maps APIs I am using this code to get the Bitmap  image

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=18&maptype=hybrid&size=560x480&markers=loc:26.177001,32.736675&sensor=false

Now I want to scroll the map, How can I do that. in other words I want algorithm to link between coordinates and gotten image size and map zoom
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You are using **Static** google maps api. That's mean you will get just a print of the map as an image. This is really useful when you want to show just a place in the map without download the javascript lib.

If you want use the map zoom, scrool and other things you have to use the javascript [google maps api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html)